# Yelp Business API 2.0 List Reviews with PHP

Tags: php, json, yelp

I am using the Yelp Business API v2.0 as documented at http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business

My goal is to list three reviews of a specific business, using PHP to make the API call and retrieve the json. I seem to only be able to fetch one review, however, with the API. I have the script prepared to loop and display all reviews returned. How can I call the API to retrieve more than one review?

I tried using the search API instead but it didn't seem to show multiple reviews either.

```
$unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/[the-business-name]";

...

// Handle Yelp response data
$response = json_decode($data, TRUE);

// for business API
foreach($response['reviews'] as $item) {
    print '<img src="' . $item['user']['image_url'] . '" alt="" /> ';
    print $item['user']['name'];
    print ' ';
    print '<img src="' . $item['rating_image_url'] . '" alt="" /><br/>';
    print $item['excerpt'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the API does not support this.
You only get a
`List of up to 1 review snippet for the business`.

The reviews array looks like this:

```
[reviews] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [rating] => 5
                    [excerpt] => I spoke with Kenneth personally and he was the one to actually come and do the work.  Price he quoted to me on the phone was still the price I was charged -...
                    [time_created] => 1370286342
                    [rating_image_url] => http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/f1def11e4e79/ico/stars/v1/stars_5.png
                    [rating_image_small_url] => http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c7623205d5cd/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_5.png
                    [user] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [image_url] => http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/cc4afe21892e/default_avatars/user_medium_square.png
                            [id] => mFrv54j7_7bRdqlmb4WLsA
                            [name] => Nancy R.
                        )

                    [rating_image_large_url] => http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/22affc4e6c38/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_5.png
                    [id] => gFrVMC7pe0IW1lzpqfCwrg
                )

        )
```

Comment: That is unfortunate. The old API used to give three reviews at least, which was bad but at least there were three. Now the API is pretty much pointless.

Comment: Something else you could try is using a web scraper. Here's something I've been working on: http://inkbud.com/wp-content/plugins/juicyreviews/get_reviews.php and the PHP that runs it:  http://pastebin.com/JVDZgctv using this library: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm Good luck!